# How can one attach to errorPlacement as a callback function in Script# using the Script# validate library?

Tags: jquery-validate, script#

There is no such property `errorPlacement` within the class `jQueryApi.Validation.jQueryValidatorOptions` and the class is sealed so I can't extend.  Any suggestions?

One can find the validation options on http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the sources... see https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/src/Libraries/jQuery/jQuery.Validation. API declarations can always use contributions to help fix/complete.

Or temporarily use Script.SetField to do it the late-bound way.

Comment: Sure, will do! Didn't know source was available, will definitely contribute! Prefer not using Script.SetField for maintainability purposes, I will extend the library to include such properties as delegates with the correct signatures from the validation plugin

Comment: I have forked the Script# repository locally and have opened the solution successfully.  I have then made some changes and rebuilt the solution which built successfully.  

Still, when referencing the DLLs output within the Script# source solution, I am getting `Error 8 The assembly '....Script.Web.dll' is not a valid script assembly.`.  I tried referencing both the Debug/Release DLLs within the following directories, `1) ...\Script#\Libraries\bin`, `2) ...\Script#\Libraries\src\Libraries\Web\obj\`

How can I reference the DLL within the Script# project in order to reflect the new changes?